# How to customize a field of model in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a field in DateTime type. I want to display this field like **2018-05-04 12:05**.

How can I do this?

**my model:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    ....
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerialer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'created_at')
```

but it display created_at like : **1990-12-31T23:59:60Z**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django rest framework list query customize json array result response because of date formating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723231/django-rest-framework-list-query-customize-json-array-result-response-because-of)

Answer (score 2):

From the [DRF serializer's doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield),

> **`format`** - A string representing the output format. If not specified,
>   this defaults to the same value as the `DATETIME_FORMAT` settings key,
>   which will be **`'iso-8601'`** unless set. Setting to a format string
>   indicates that `to_representation` return values should be coerced to
>   string output. Format strings are described below. Setting this value
>   to `None` indicates that Python `datetime` objects should be returned by
>   `to_representation`. In this case the datetime encoding will be
>   determined by the renderer.

you could do it by specifying the **`format`** parameter of [**`DateTimeField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) for serializer.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('name', 'created_at')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the format.

```
created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", required=False, read_only=True)
```

Change the format in which type you want. If you want change for all datetime then change in the setting file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ",
```

}